# React (Routes and Redirect) component does not working

Tags: reactjs, redirect, components, react-router-dom

```
import { Routes, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const Body = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Route path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/menu" component={Menu} />
      <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
      <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Body;
```

[image: My Menu section is not working]

Comment: What version of `react-router-dom` are you trying to use? Where is any redirect being rendered. See [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

instead `<div>` wrap you routes to `<Router>` and `<Switch>` like this:

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';

....
return (
 <Router>
  <Switch>
     <Route ...>
      ....
  </Switch>
 </Router>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where any redirect is being used, but for the provided code example:

If you are trying to use `react-router-dom@5` then there is no exported `Routes` component. Import `Route` and `Switch` and render accordingly. Remember to order the routes in inverse order of path specificity.

```
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

const Body = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/menu" component={Menu} />
        <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        <Route path="/" component={Home} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
};
```

If you are using `react-router-dom@6` then import the `Route` component for the routes. The `Routes` component wraps the `Route` components. Remember that RRDv6 `Route` components render their content on the `element` prop ***as JSX***. Route order doesn't matter now as a route ranking system is used.

```
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const Body = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/menu" element={<Menu />} />
        <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
        <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
};
```